# Make this use pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I want this to use `pd.concat` since datetime64[ns] is deprecated. Problem is I don't know how.

Here is the code:

```
ads_hour['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ads_hour['Date'], errors='coerce')
ads['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ads['Time'], errors='coerce')

merge_columns_ads_hour = "Date"
merge_columns_ads = "Time"

merged_ads_hour_ads = pd.merge(ads_hour, ads, left_on=merge_columns_ads_hour, right_on=merge_columns_ads)

merge_columns_advertising = "TV"

allData = pd.merge(merged_ads_hour_ads, advertising, left_on=merge_columns_ads, right_on=merge_columns_advertising)

# Display the first few rows of the merged DataFrame
print(allData.head())
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Could you please write in more detail what you want?

Comment: pd.concat will not resolve any problems you have with datetime values. Please provide simple reproducible code  and data which demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pd.concat` instead of `pd.merge` for merging DataFrames based on datetime columns, you can concatenate the DataFrames along the appropriate axis. Here's how you can change your code:

```
ads_hour['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ads_hour['Date'], errors='coerce')
ads['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ads['Time'], errors='coerce')

# Use pd.concat to merge based on datetime columns
merged_ads_hour_ads = pd.concat([ads_hour.set_index('Date'), ads.set_index('Time')], axis=1, join='inner')

# Reset the index to make 'Date' a column again
merged_ads_hour_ads.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Assuming 'Time' is in both DataFrames, you can now use pd.concat again
allData = pd.concat([merged_ads_hour_ads, advertising.set_index('TV')], axis=1, join='inner')

# Reset the index to make 'TV' a column again
allData.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Display the first few rows of the merged DataFrame
print(allData.head())
```

In this code, `set_index` is used to set the datetime columns as the index before concatenation, and `reset_index` is used afterward to convert the index back to a column. The `join='inner'` parameter ensures that only rows with matching datetime values are included in the final result.

Comment: This reads a lot like something that comes out of ChatGPT. Paste the question into it, ask for code comments and you'll get an extremely similar answer format.